# Moving methods out of Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this in one of my Codeigniter controllers. But I would like it to be accessible to other controllers but I think $this keyword would have a different meaning, whilst it needs to refer to the controller that it is loaded into.

```
function checkSecurity($user, $page)
{
    if($this->mod_backend->canUserAccessPage($user, $page))
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view($page, $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');       
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('unauthorised', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need that a method will be accesible to all controllers in your app, you can implement a class in `MY_Controller.php` file and then all your controller must extend this class instead of `CI_Controller`.

For example in MY_Controller.php

```
<?php

class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function checkSecurity($user, $page)
    {
        if($this->mod_backend->canUserAccessPage($user, $page))
        {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view($page, $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');       
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('unauthorised', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');               
        }
    }

}
```

And then in your controller you must extend this class:

```
<?php

class Other_Controller extends My_Controller{
   //Do the stuff

   //You can call your function in every controller
   $this->checkSecurity('my_user', 'my_page');


}
```

Comment: The other nice thing about doing it this way is you can do things in the MY_Controller constructor that you want to happen every time a page is loaded regardless of the controller that loads the page.

Comment: Yeah, only remember in your controller call parent::__construct();